# Superfields over superspaces

Tags: supersymmetry, superspace-formalism

Suppose that we have an $n$-dimensional vector space $X$ together with a basis $\{\theta_i\}^n_{i = 1}\in X$.

$$\bigwedge(X) = \mathbb{C}\oplus\bigwedge^1(X)\oplus\bigwedge^2(X)\oplus\cdots\oplus\bigwedge^n(X) = \bigoplus^n_{i = 1}\bigwedge^{i}(X)$$

In which every $z\in \bigwedge(X)$ can be written uniquely as $$z = z_{0}+z_{i}\theta_{i}+\frac{1}{2}z_{ij}\theta_{i}\theta_{j}+\ldots+\frac{1}{%
n!}z_{i_{1}\ldots i_{n}}\theta_{i_{1}}\ldots\theta_{i_{n}}$$

While also satisfying the anti-commutation $\{\theta_i, \theta_j\} = \theta_{i}\theta_j+\theta_{j}\theta_{i} = 0$ for every $1\leq i, j\leq n$.

Then if we define Grasmann parity in $\bigwedge(X)$ as

$$\overline{z} = \begin{cases}0, z = z_{0}+\frac{1}{2}z_{ij}\theta_{i}\theta_{j}+\ldots+\frac{1}{(2n)
!}z_{i_{1}\ldots i_{2n}}\theta_{i_{1}}\ldots\theta_{i_{2n}} \\\ 1, z = z_{i}\theta_{i}+\frac{1}{6}z_{ijk}\theta_{i}\theta_{j}\theta_{k}
+\ldots+\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}z_{i_{1}\ldots i_{2n+1}}\theta_{i_{1}}\ldots\theta_{i
_{2n+1}}\end{cases}$$

Grasmann-even parts and Grasmann-odd parts will be commuting and anti-commuting respectively. In $d = 4$, $\mathcal{N} = 1$, a complex superfield is of the form

$$\begin{align}\Psi(x,\theta , {\bar {\theta }}) = \phi (x)+\theta\chi(x)+{\bar{\theta}}{\bar {\chi}}'(x)+{\bar {\theta }}\sigma^{\mu}\theta V_{\mu }(x)+\theta^{2}F(x)+{\bar {\theta }}^{2}{\bar{F}}'(x)+{\bar{\theta }}^{2}\theta \xi (x)& + \theta^{2}{\bar {\theta}}{\bar{\xi }}'(x)+\theta ^{2}{\bar{\theta}}^{2}D(x).\end{align}$$

Can we say that the complex fields ${\displaystyle \phi , V_{\mu}, F, {\bar {F}}', D}$ represent bosonic degrees of freedom, while the complex fields ${\displaystyle \chi ,{\bar {\chi}}', \xi, {\bar {\xi}}'}$ represent fermionic degrees of freedom in the representation of $\bigwedge(X)$?

Comment: Hi Cake. Welcome to Phys.SE. The answer is yes. Is there a reason you ask?

Comment: @Qmechanic Thank you very much. Yes, I wanted to make sure that Grasmann-even (${\displaystyle \phi , V_{\mu}, F, {\bar {F}}', D}$) and Grasmann-odd (${\displaystyle \chi ,{\bar {\chi}}', \xi, {\bar {\xi}}'}$) parts of the Grasmann algebra $\bigwedge(X)$ correspond to bosonic and fermionic degrees of freedom, respectively.